# I have an automated table, I can get a header on top but I also want one on the left

Tags: php, html, html-table, tableheader

I am very new to PHP and html, for school I need to make a website that calculates monetary exchange rates.

Now for the calculator itself everything works. But to make it look more professional I added a table with borders etc. Then I added a table header on top but I also want to put one on the left side of my table. I just can't figure out where to put what.

This is my code so far (probably contains many mistakes. just ignore them,  this is only for the table.)

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{

$valuta=$_POST['valuta'];
$wisselkoers=$_POST['wisselkoers'];

echo "<table border=1px>";
echo "<th>0</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th>";

for($tiental=0; $tiental<100; $tiental=$tiental+10)
{

    echo "<tr>";
    for($eenheden=0; $eenheden<10; $eenheden=$eenheden+1)
    {
        $uitkomst = ($tiental+$eenheden)* $wisselkoers;

        echo"<td> ".$uitkomst."</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";

}
// (HTML after this)
```

Comment: add another `<th> -1 </th>` for it (with the rest of them), and then after you do `<tr>`, you want to put a `<td> left column </td>` before you enter the `for` statement.

Comment: Your table headings aren't wrapped in a <tr>

Comment: a few notes:  your `<th>0</th><th>...` needs to be wrapped in a `<tr>....</tr>`.  you can even take that further, and wrap it in a `<thead><tr><th> 0 </th><th> 1 </th> ... </tr></thead>`, too.  and `$eenheden=$eenheden+1` can be re-written as `$eenheden++` just to make it shorter (if you want).

Comment: excellent first post on stack overflow, though...

Comment: Thankyou very much for the quick replies. All works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{

$valuta=$_POST['valuta'];
$wisselkoers=$_POST['wisselkoers'];

echo "<table border=1px>";
echo "<tr><th>0</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th><th>10</th></tr>";

for($tiental=0; $tiental<100; $tiental=$tiental+10)
{

echo "<tr><th>HEADER LEFT SIDE CONTENT</th>";
for($eenheden=0; $eenheden<10; $eenheden=$eenheden+1)
{
    $uitkomst = ($tiental+$eenheden)* $wisselkoers;

    echo"<td> ".$uitkomst."</td>";
}
echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";

}
```

I hope this is usefull.